# add_filter the_content doesn't work

Tags: filters, the-content

I just made a plugin with some meta data and such. I need to alter the content when, but my add_filter('the_content') doesn't do anything...

Code:

```
public function run() { 
    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'enqueue_scripts' ) );
    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'enqueue_styles' ) );
    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'add_meta_box' ) );

    add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save_post' ) );
    // HERE IS MY PROBLEM:
    add_filter( 'the_content', array( $this, 'some_content_method' ) );

}


public function some_content_method( $content ) {

    var_dump('Why u no?');
    $content .= 'Why u no work?';
    return $content;
}
```

If I write 'add_meta_boxes' the dump will work.

```
    // HERE IS MY PROBLEM:
    add_filter( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'some_content_method' ) );
```

If I change it to add_action instead of add_filter nothing happens either

```
    // HERE IS MY PROBLEM:
    add_action( 'the_content', array( $this, 'some_content_method' ) );
```

everything else works - can anybody help?

Comment: How does `run()` get executed?

Comment: It's in a admin/class.php

un by the main plugin php file:

function run_acme_plugin() {

    $plugin = new Acme_Plugin();
    $plugin->run();

}
run_acme_plugin();

And that works just fine, because it works when I substitute the content for add_meta_boxes. everything works just fine, just not the 'the_content'

Comment: OK, just making sure it wasn't only added on admin requests. So just to clarify, you're using `the_content()` function on a front end request and not seeing the filtered content there?

Comment: I am using: add_filter( '**the_content**', array( $this, 'some_content_method' ) );

and I've create some_content_method() in which I var_dump() something - and nothing happens....

If I call: add_filter( '**add_meta_boxes**', array( $this, 'some_content_method' ) ); instead, my var_dump is shown

I don't understand why.

Comment: My question is *where* you are expecting to see this filtered content. It's not typically used anywhere on admin screens, it's a front end function/filter for templates. It seems like you're doing admin screen stuff.

Comment: Litterally 3 seconds before I read your reply it occured to me, that it might not be an admin feature.
New to WordPress, I understand it can be hard to answer nonsensical questions :) Sorry bout that - I'll accept your answer since you did provide me with the answer I needed. :)

Comment: If you'll just make a reply I can accept :)

Comment: Well, you did eventually get there on your own :) You can add answers to your own questions and get those sweet rep points.

Answer (score 1):

With help from Milo I realised that 'the_content' wasn't meant for the admin part of WP, which is why I didn't see my var_dump as I expected.

Conclusion: A rookie mistake!